# Show A Sticky Bar Until User Scrolls Down to a <div>

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to add a sticky bar at bottom of my page and I want it to fade out once user reaches to a div by scrolling and again fade in once user scrolls up and that div is not on screen anymore.

And it shouldn't show if user screen is big enough to show that div normally.

Please guys help me...

I am currently using this code:-

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
$(window).bind("scroll", function() {
    if ($(this).scrollTop() > -1) { //Fade in at a level of height
        $("#bottbar").fadeIn();
        checkOffset();
    } else {
        $("#bottbar").stop().fadeOut();
    }
});
function checkOffset() {
    if($('#bottbar').offset().top + $('#bottbar').height() >= $('#stopDiv').offset().top) {
        $('#bottbar').css('position', 'absolute');
    }
    if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() < $('#stopDiv').offset().top) {
        $('#bottbar').css('position', 'fixed'); // restore when you scroll up
   }
}
//]]>
</script>
```

but it is not working as expected on my site bookaire.com

I am not sure whats the problem is with this code, it doesn't show the bar when site loads, it show only when user scrolls a little and when it reaches the `stopdiv` instead of hiding the bar it get stuck at center of screen.

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? Please show your code and expected outcome.

Comment: @KyleSevenoaks added the code, please check it once more..

Comment: You should tell us what the problem is with your current code too

Comment: @OGHaza Thanx for the reply, I have add the detail you said, please check it it can make it clear.

Comment: @RiteshKumar, I have no idea what the answer is, but I voted to reopen and the question is open now so hopefully someone can help

Comment: you can base your logic on this: http://codepen.io/vsync/pen/Kgcoa

Comment: thanx @vsync I don't have any idea in JavaScript can anyone please give more clear answer...I have found this tutorial http://yafasu.blogspot.in/2013/09/how-to-make-div-fade-inout-when.html but don't know how to customize it to show by default and without showing the actual div below.

Comment: @OGHaza thanx for reopening this. I enjoyed the challenge even though the question was poorly asked. I think my solution below should work although it doesn't have a cool fade in/out transition

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whew! that took me a while since I'm still a beginner with javascript but I think I got it.
Note: the bar is getting stuck in the middle on certain screen size because you are only changing the position from fixed to absolute in your javascript.  instead, change the display from block to hidden.
Also note that the css for `#bottbar` should already be `display:block`
I believe your requirements are:
1. it shouldn't show if user screen is big enough to show that div normally
2. to fade out once user reaches to a div by scrolling

See: [**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/MilkyTech/tMuwR/2/)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    if($(window).height() > $('#stopDiv').offset().top) {
        $("#bottbar").css('display', 'none'); 
    }
    else {
        $("#bottbar").css('display', 'block');
    }
});
$(window).bind("scroll", function() {
    if($(window).height() > $('#stopDiv').offset().top) {
        $("#bottbar").css('display', 'none');
    }
    if ($(this).scrollTop() > -1) { //Fade in at a level of height
        $("#bottbar").css('display', 'block');
        checkOffset();
    } 
    else {
        $("#bottbar").css('display', 'none');
    }
});
function checkOffset() {
    if($('#bottbar').offset().top + $('#bottbar').height() >= $('#stopDiv').offset().top) {
        $('#bottbar').css('display', 'none');
    }
    if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() < $('#stopDiv').offset().top) {
        $('#bottbar').css('display', 'block'); // restore when you scroll up
   }
}
```

Comment: Great!! You Are Great Sir, You really solved my problem, thanx alot... for me you are not a beginner, you are a genius :) thanks once again.

Comment: Worked nicely thanks!